# Connection test failed: Command failed: npm install --prefix /tmp/strapi9a8613f466ed strapi-connector-bookshelf@3.6.3 knex@0.21.18 pg@8.5.1

Tags: strapi, nvm, npx, enoent

Running Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
Node 15.2.0 and npm 7.0.8
Strapi Version 3.6.3

Minimum requirements listed on Strapi Docs
Software
Minimum version    Recommended version
Node.js 12.x        14.x
npm     6.x         6.x
Steps to recreate, create new directory on server

npx create-strapi-app my-project
? Choose your installation type Custom (manual settings)
? Choose your default database client postgres
? Database name: name
? Host: 127.0.0.1
? Port: 5432
? Username: name
? Password: *********
? Enable SSL connection: No
Connection test failed: Command failed: npm install --prefix /tmp/strapi9a8613f466ed strapi-connector-bookshelf@3.6.3 knex@0.21.18 pg@8.5.1
Double checked permissions on /tmp/ 777

Other Strapi instances set up and connected to other postgres databases on the same server.

Answer (score 0):

I could not find this error or anything like it online so I created this question in case someone else ran into it or I did in the future and could not remember what solved it.

In my case updating node and npm solved the problem, even though there was a suitable version installed.
Node was installed with NVM so the command
nvm install node
Updated node and npm and sovled the problem.